# There is some way to do this string extraction faster?

Tags: php, algorithm, string, pattern-matching

I need to extract the virtual host name of a HTTP request.
Since this willl be done for every request, I´m searching for the fastest way to do this.

The following code and times are just some of the ways I had studied.

So, there is some faster way to do this?

```
$hostname = "alphabeta.gama.com";

$iteractions = 100000;

//While Test

$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i < $iteractions; $i++){
    $vhost = "";
    while(($i < 20) && ($hostname{$i} != '.')) $vhost .= $hostname{$i++};
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
$timewhile = $time_end - $time_start;

//Regexp Test
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$iteractions; $i++){
    $vhost = "";
    preg_match("/([A-Za-z])*/", $hostname ,$vals);
    $vhost = $vals[0];
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$timeregex = $time_end - $time_start;

//Substring Test
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<$iteractions;$i++){
    $vhost = "";
    $vhost = substr($hostname,0,strpos($hostname,'.'));
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$timesubstr = $time_end - $time_start;

//Explode Test
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<$iteractions;$i++){
    $vhost = "";
    list($vhost) = explode(".",$hostname);
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$timeexplode = $time_end - $time_start;

//Strreplace Test. Must have the final part of the string fixed.
$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<$iteractions;$i++){
    $vhost = "";
    $vhost = str_replace(".gama.com","",$hostname);
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$timereplace = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "While   :".$timewhile."\n";
echo "Regex   :".$timeregex."\n";
echo "Substr  :".$timesubstr."\n";
echo "Explode :".$timeexplode."\n";
echo "Replace :".$timereplace."\n";
```

And as result timings:

```
While   :0.0886390209198
Regex   :1.22981309891
Substr  :0.338994979858
Explode :0.450794935226
Replace :0.33411693573
```

Comment: Are sure if it's a slower part of your code? Performance optimization should be done to slowest code first, otherwise it can be waste.

Comment: Agreed, but now it´s the time for the small things ;)

Comment: @Ivan -exactly. If you are following this by a database connection, you are wasting your time. remember you aren't doing this 100k times for each request. even with your slowest method, you would be adding a total of 1.2 seconds for every 100k requests.

Comment: Your while check is incorrect. You keep using the `$i` variable, but you need a new one. This will work: `for($k = 0; $k < strlen($hostname) && $hostname != '.'; $vhost .= $hostname{$k++});`. That turns out to be the slowest options of them all.

Comment: Well, getting the length of the hostname before the iterations start will half the execution time, but it's still the slowest option.

Comment: You can also think about caching or even rewriting this code of lower level

Comment: @Ivan Nevostruev: You are incomplete in stating "can be a waste", you should have stated: "can **and will** be awaste" or more to the point "is a waste". But i still upvoted your comment.

Comment: Corrected the problem with the for and while loop variable.
Timing is now "While   :0.211617946625"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the strtok() function:

```
$vhost = strtok($hostname, ".")
```

It's faster than a correct version of your while loop, *and* much more readable.

Comment: Strtok timing :0.234637975693

Comment: @Ville Nice idea. @Renato, this is an improvment of about 2 microseconds from the slowest one. nice work. lol

Comment: By the way, since speed is so important to you, are you using a PHP accelerator of some sort?

Comment: Hey Ville,

I´m accepting your answer. It´s not faster then the while option, but it´s trully much more readable.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it the substr() way.

```
$vhost = substr($host, 0, strstr($host, "."));
```

And I really don't think that the way how you split this string would affect performance in any real-world program. 100 000 iterations is quite huge... ;-)

Comment: Alex, you, Ivan, Byron and any other person who says that it´s a waste of time 'this optimization' in a real world application are right.

I´m just looking for the answer to the question: "Is there any faster way to do this?"

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Alright. Out of interest, how fast is substr($host, 0, strstr($host, "."))?

Comment: strpos instead of strstr should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$iterations = 100000;
$fullhost = 'subdomain.domain.tld';

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) 
{
    $vhost = substr($fullhost, 0, strpos($fullhost, '.'));
}

$total = microtime(true) - $start;
printf( 'extracted %s from %s %d times in %s seconds', $vhost, $fullhost, $iterations, number_format($total,5));
?>
```

extracted subdomain from subdomain.domain.tld 100000 times in 0.44695 seconds

But that was while encoding video, so it will likely be faster under better circumstances.

Comment: hehe, i missed the fact you already had this in your code but notied the kinda awkward (to me) strstr usage of Alex and i felt like trying this.